# adding meta og:image property to share custom facebook links using boostrap and flask

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-share

I have a website called [www.caminemosjuntos.com.ar](http://www.caminemosjuntos.com.ar) and I add the facebook share link button but the default preview image is not what I want to show. So I try to add <meta og:image property inside the head to customize it but when I debug the page I notice that browser is rendering inside the body tag.
I'm using python-flask with boostrap and templates.
This is how start my header.html:

'''

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.caminemosjuntos.com.ar/static/img/pathway.jpeg" />
```

'''

and browser is rendering from post section: (post.html include header.html)

'''

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.caminemosjuntos.com.ar/static/img/pathway.jpeg">
    <title>Caminemos juntos</title>
```

'''

How can I do to fix this? Facebook is still saying that I don't have explicitly the og:image.

Thanks

Comment: _"Facebook is still saying that I don't have explicitly the og:image."_ - looks like you simply didn't clear the cache by having Facebook re-scrape the URL - it says no such thing any more currently, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.caminemosjuntos.com.ar

Comment: thanks @CBroe After I add some metatags and clear cache/extrac again, I can see the content of meta properties updated from facebook debug tool, but I still didn't see the update if I click the share buttom from my website. any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that my main website is now working as expected, but not my others sections.  Despite I use templates for the header and footer, do I need to add meta tags to each html?

Comment: The HTML returned by each URL has to return them, how you achieve that on the server side, is up to you.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your image could be too big try reducing the size or try a smaller image. Try different sizes and resolutions.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: thanks for your help. As i answered above: I noticed that my main website is now working as expected, but not my others sections. Despite I use templates for the header and footer, do I need to add meta tags to each html?